# Assembler SegFail

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit

So guys I got problem . I'm trying just to change one letter in this easy string "Hello World"
so I'm trying assign value to memory cell like this

```
.section    .text
string:
    .ascii "Hello, world!"
length:
    .quad . -string     #Dot = 'here'

.globl _start       #Make entry point visible to linker
_start:
    movl $4, %eax       #4=write
    movl $1, %ebx       #1=stdout
    movl $string, %ecx
    movl length, %edx
    int $0x80       #Call Operating System



    movl $98,4(%ecx)   #Critical moment why cannot I do this?
    movl $98,string(,%ebx,1)  #cannot do this too ;(


    movl $4, %eax       #4=write
    movl $1, %ebx       #1=stdout
    movl $string, %ecx
    movl length, %edx
    int $0x80 





    movl $0, %ebx       #Make program return syscall exit status
    movl $1, %eax       #1=exit
    int $0x80       #Call System Again
```

and additional info I'm working at x64(linux) and   assembling it in emulation mode x32 by linux gas so should be all right , TY for replies

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? Is it an error? Is something not working correctly? Thanks.

Comment: It was Segmentation Fault cuz I didn't know thats .text section is read only and I tried write here some data 
but Jester already helped me :P TY for reply mate

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put your string into the `.text` section, which is read-only. You should put it into the `.data` section (but don't forget to switch back to `.text` for the program code).

Comment: Yea it was this ,ty for helping me at my beginning :)